# Disable Paypal post-robot messaging on checkout.js - how to turn off debug mode

Tags: javascript, paypal, console.log, post-robot

I've tried few approaches to disable Paypal post-robot debug messages on my browser's console but none seemed to work.

The reason these messages can be quite annoying is that they make debugging the browser harder because there is plenty of them, hiding some other console warnings.

The console logs are coming from Paypal checkout.js file which is loaded as external resource on our domain.

Only thing I have found about debugging on Paypal developers page is here:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/in-context/javascript_advanced_settings/?mark=debug

I have tried indeed to invert the condition like `document.cookie="PPDEBUG=false"`. However, I'm still seeing the debug messaging coming through because this should be set on a cookie on the paypal sandbox domain.

Example of the console messages:

```
> ppxo_current_protocol_https Object {timestamp: 148465111111111,
> windowID: "4250cccccc", pageID: "7bd8cccccc", host:
> "www.project.local", path:
> "/projectlocal/fr/checkout/single"…} checkout.js:4617

> ppxo_setup_production Object {timestamp: 148465111111111, windowID:
> "4250cccccc", pageID: "7bd8cccccc", host: "www.project.local",
> path: "/projectlocal/fr/checkout/single"…}
```

Here another link related: https://github.com/krakenjs/post-robot

Comment: Did you try the inverse of what's described in the documentation link you posted - open your browser console while your page is loaded and run `document.cookie="PPDEBUG=false"`?

Comment: Yes, of course I tried. No luck though. :)

Comment: There's an open issue highlighting a solution for this on the GitHub page:
https://github.com/krakenjs/post-robot/issues/11

No idea if that config is exposed to you on the express checkout implementation though, but probably worth looking into :)

Comment: Nope, unfortunately that config is not exposed to me. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 4):

If you're using chrome, you can set up regex filters

```
^(?!.*?(ppxo|xc_|post-robot))
```

[image: With Filter]

[image: Without Filter]

Comment: Yes I have also tried something like this and it's a good temporary solution before Paypal updates their configs to allow paypal express checkout js setup to be initialised with debug as false. +1

Answer (score 1):

Loading `checkout.js` with a log level set to 'error' will prevent the 'debug' and 'info' level messages:

```
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js" data-log-level="error"></script>
```

When looking at the JS code from [checkout.js](https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js), this seems to be the only option:

`logLevel: currentScript.getAttribute("data-log-level"),`

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work up to a certain level. It filters out all other console logs but of course still shows the errors. Paypal should provide a way to switch off completely all log messages.  +1